# Next.js - Incremental Static Regeneration fails (404) on production/Vercel.com

Tags: next.js, vercel

I'm using Next.js + Wordpress/Graphql as headless CMS and deploying to Vercel.

I'm getting a 404 when new posts are created on production (vercel) - not happening locally or when using `next build`. Strangely, it solves the problem when I redeploy or when I push a new version to the repo and vercel does a fresh build.

I guess this has something to do with the [Incremental Static Regeneration](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration)?

I had a similar but slightly different issue with a previous Wordpress server that was responding with 429 Too Many Requests. *But* that was a problem with the first build when all pages were generated and therefore more requests were made. I've switched to another server that seemed to fix the problem and now the problem only occurs after the first build (i.e. when incrementally regenerating pages on request).

Here is one of the problem pages:
https://github.com/garethfoote/blind-ditch/blob/master/pages/projects/%5Bslug%5D.js

Thought this could be the culprit but I'm not getting any remote logs from in [console.re](https://console.re/):

```
  if (!router.isFallback && !project?.slug) {
    console.re.log("404??", project);
    return <ErrorPage statusCode={404} />;
  }
```

I'm struggling to work out what is causing this and also how I might further debug this on Vercel. Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging around I realised that I had not fully understood the use of the `fallback` key in `getStaticPaths`.

I assumed ISR would generate new pages that weren't specified in the `paths` object of `getStaticPaths` at build time but I know realise that is what  `fallback: true` or `fallback: "blocking"` does.

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#fallback-true